# The PUSHAD POPAD or using the "USES" operator

Tags: assembly

I am a new user to assembly language and am using the book assembly language by kip irvine, and he talks about using the PUSHAD AND POPAD to save the general registers on the stack. Irvine said if you are writing procedures that modify any of the registers you need to use PUSHAD AND POPAD to save and restore the registers after you have called the procedure.

I wanted to know is it better and more correct and efficient to use the "USES" operator to  just save and restore the registers you use within your procedure (e.g. if you only use the EAX and ECX registers) , or should you just save and restore all the registers.

Comment: IIRC, USES is assembler-specific sugar while PUSHx/POPx are CPU-level commands. The latter are more universal. It doesn't have to be PUSHAD, by the way, you can PUSH/POP just the registers that you trash.

Comment: You should also be aware of the calling convention that you should follow. Usually there are some registers that you may modify freely, so no point preserving those. Also makes returning values tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

USES is assembler specific. In general, you want to avoid assembler-specific directives as much as possible because they reduce the portability of your code. Also, anyone not using your assembler will have no idea what "USES" means.

`PUSHAD` and `POPAD` persist the general purpose register set and are usually a good way to save registers for typical long procedures. For short procedures which use few registers, or for situations where you are passing values inside of registers (rather than on the stack), you should manually push/pop, rather than use PUSHAD.

Answer (score 0):

I think `pushad` should typically be avoided, since it generally does more than necessary.  I haven't micro-benchmarked, but I would guess it's slower when you're not using *every* general purpose register.  It's also not available in the x86-64 bit instruction set.

`USES` is *masm* specific, but every assembler typically has some form of macro expansion (*nasm*, *yasm*, etc...)  to eliminate the need for copy-paste coding.  Another example would be *yasm* [multipush](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html#nasm-macro-rotate).